# Jquery getElementById - multiple instances within one script tag?

Tags: jquery, html, getelementbyid

My current script identifies an element in my HTML with this line

```
document.getElementById("one" ).src = images[random_no];
```

Is there a way to use one instance of  on multiple ids - in my case image tags. This current script affects only one image with its effect. I want to use that one script to affect multiple images in my code.

```
document.getElementById("one, two, three" ).src = images[random_no];
```

I know that doesn't work :) just trying to further illustrate :)

Answer (score 3):

in Jquery

```
$("#one,#two,#three").attr('src',images[random_no]);
```

try using this code

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/MYua5/1/

```
i=0;
$("#one, #two, #three" ).attr("src", function() {
    i++;
    return i+'.jpg';
});
```

Random generation of images

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/MYua5/3/

```
function randomFromInterval(from, to) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}
var images = new Array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg');
var len = images.length;
$("#one, #two, #three").each(function () {
    x = randomFromInterval(0, len-1);
    var img_no = (x >= 0 && x < len) ? x : randomFromInterval(0, len-1);
    $(this).attr('src', images[img_no]);
});
```

new code

working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/MYua5/4/

```
var images = new Array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg');
var len = images.length;
i = 0;

function getImages() {
    $("#one, #two, #three").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', images[i]).attr('alt', images[i]);
        if (i == len-1) {
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
        console.log(i);
    });
}
getImages();
setInterval(getImages, 1000);
```

Comment: That will set them all to the **same** image, which seems like it's probably not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't really make it work, I have 5 images I would like to rotate so the users don't see them twice...I've managed to get one image to rotate but I don't want to make 5 script tags for each image...so I'm trying to figure out how to make one control all img's with id

Comment: what you want pls tell and explain

Comment: I have 5 images assigned <img id=1 ... 2, 3, 4, 5...and I have 10 images...I want to rotate those 10 images in those 5 img id's

Comment: @user1429247 so check my answer using array method splice()

Comment: That one works! Can I somehow set it to switch images in order (1,2,3...) instead of random?

Comment: @user1429247 ya for sure you don't need to use any random method but in what it is related to your opening question?  FYI, using index of each loop would be enough

Comment: Got it working. The only thing I'm not happy with is the randomization...it seems it randomizes pretty lazy, I have to refresh a lot of times before actually having "fresh" set of images...

Is it possible to just one up the images? For instance, 3 divs with images 11.jpg, 21.jpg and 31.jpg....and then make it go on up on every refresh - 12.jpg, 22.jpg, 32.jpg, and on next refresh 13.jpg 23.jpg 33.jpg ...would have lot more control than leave it to dubious randomizing pattern

Comment: @user1429247 you should use some persistant data storage. FYI, if you want to speak to a specific person, use '@' followed by pseudo or only answserer will get a notification.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers here show you how to set all three to the *same* image.

If you want them each to get *different* images, then:

```
$("#one, #two, #three" ).attr("src", function() {
    /* ...generate new random_no here... */
    return images[random_no];
});
```

If you pass a function into [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) as the second argument, it gets called for each element in the set, and the return value is used for the attribute value.

Comment: You could have used the classical each loop which is little faster here as i'm aware of but who cares for 3 images ;)

Comment: @roasted: Color me surprised! http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-prop-vs-each-speed But if we care about speed, we're much better off with `$("#one").add("#two").add("#three")`: http://jsperf.com/ways-to-look-up-two-elements-by-id-jquery/2 Again, though, this is premature- and micro-optimization. :-)

Comment: I didn't think `.add()` would be faster, good to know! Anyway, still regarding performance, i don't think something can beat this: `$([document.getElementById('one'), document.getElementById('two')])` but who knows?!...  http://jsperf.com/ways-to-look-up-two-elements-by-id-jquery/3  (sorry, i just revisited your jsperf)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and combine ids with comma using  [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$("#one, #two, #three" ).attr(href,images[random_no]);
```

**ID Selector (“#id”)**

> For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function
>   document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. When another
>   selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery
>   performs an additional check before identifying the element as a
>   match, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

**Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)**

> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single
>   result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to
>   select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the
>   returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in
>   document order. An alternative to this combinator is the .add()
>   method, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) - id prefixed with `#` with [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) - selectors separated by `,` here

```
$("#one, #two, #three").attr('src',images[random_no]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a variable number of images and don't want to insert the id of each of them into the array, you could try using `.each()`.

```
$(".class").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', images[random_no]);
});
```

You then need to add the class to the images you want, instead of using their ids.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

However, if you definitely want to avoid using class, you can separate Ids by a comma:

```
$("#segement1,#segement2,#segement3").attr('src',images[random_no]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want same image twice:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JXxZD/)

```
var images = new Array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg');
$("#one, #two, #three").each(function(){
    var l = images.length,
        random_no = Math.floor(l*Math.random());    
    $(this).attr('src',images[random_no]);
    images.splice(random_no,1);    
});
```